# Console.Log(Object Number) - Object of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, console.log

Using Angular2 and Firebase I'm retrieving a news article.

I log my retrieved data and its appearing as an Object with an array of Objects but there is only 1 item in the array starting at **39**.

Can i get the **39** so i can retrieve this object?

Or is there another way?

Thanks

GWS

```
    this._ReturnsService.fetchDataId(id)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.news = data[39];
            this.bodyofartical = this.news.body.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        })
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand what your question is. You’re already using `data[39]` which already accesses that object. What exactly isn’t working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Object.keys(data)[0]` which would return the `39` you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with following code and expend as needed.

```
this._ReturnsService.fetchDataId(id)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach( d => {
            this.bodyofartical = d.news.body.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        }
    })
```

With above code you don't have to worry about index id.

The code will loop through the whole `data` array.

You will have to modify the loop if there is more than 1 item in `data` array, else `this.bodyofartical` will always get the last article in the array.